# install opencv-2.4 in beagleboard zm rev c (12.04)

Tags: 12.04, opencv, beagleboard

I'm running `ubuntu-12.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+omap.img` in my BBxm. I want to install `opencv-2.4` for a software dependency, but apt-get install only gives me `opencv-2.3`.

I want to avoid manual installation, as I am not that expert.

RobertNelson's rcn repository is having `opencv-2.4`. Please help me to find that repository, so that I can add it in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and install it through:

```
apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the following commands to add the [ppa:yjwong/opencv2](https://launchpad.net/~yjwong/+archive/ubuntu/opencv2) to your sources:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yjwong/opencv2
sudo apt-get update
```

Now to install the `libopencv-dev` package (version 2.4.8) on your 12.04 system:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

To check the installed version:

```
$ dpkg-query -W libopencv-dev
libopencv-dev   2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1ppa1~precise1
```

Comment: thanks for reply ..i will execute the command and come back...

Comment: it worked thankyou....now a small question..What if two repos conflict for same package ? how to choose one of them of our choice ?

Comment: apt will automatically select the most recent version.